# Sorting a data with characters and numbers into numbers in R

Tags: r

I have a list of data with results that include numbers and also include text.

Example data:

```
df$col_1 
Neg 
Negative 
32 
16 
64 
8 
128 
4 
not done 
Pos 
Missing 
?Pos 
~2 
? 240
```

What I have done is create a new column and try to re-code the data.

```
 df$col <- NA df$col [ which (df$col_1=="Positive" )] <- 1 
 df$col [ which (df$col_1=="2" )] <- 1 
 df$col [ which (df$col_1=="Negative" )] <- 1
```

Rather than coding every possible combination, as above, What I would like to do is be able to create a list of negatives, positives and NA values.

I tried this

```
list <- c ("2","4","8","16","32")
df$col [ which (df$col_1=="list" )] <- 1
```

But this did not work.

Every number should be considered positive, unless there is a question mark. So I wondered whether I could convert all numbers to numeric?

For all the miscellaneous text, other than positive and negative, I want to put NA.

```
df$col_1        df$col
Neg             0
Negative        0
32              1 
16              1
64              1
8               1
128             1
4               1
not done        NA
Pos             1
Missing         NA
?Pos            NA
~2              1
? 240           NA
```

Comment: Use `%in%` instead of `==` and `list` would be without quotes

Comment: Your example input and example output are hard to understand. I think I've figured it out, but you should try to make them more readable. You also replace everything with 1 in your code, but in your example output some values are replaced with 0, which is confusing.

Comment: Nevermind about the input and output, I've add triple backticks to make the structure visible.

Answer (score 7):

You potentially have a fairly complex set of conditions, so you might be better of using regular expressions with `ifelse` and `sapply`. For instance, below I use `grepl` in nested `ifelse`s:

```r
df$col <- sapply(df$col_1,
       function(x) ifelse(grepl("^((~)?\\d+)$|^([pP]os(itive)?)$", x),
                          1,
                          ifelse(grepl("^[nN]eg(ative)?$", x), 0, NA)
                          )
       )

#### OUTPUT ####

      col_1 col
1       Neg   0
2  Negative   0
3        32   1
4        16   1
5        64   1
6         8   1
7       128   1
8         4   1
9  not done  NA
10      Pos   1
11  Missing  NA
12     ?Pos  NA
13       ~2   1
14        ?  NA
15      240   1
```

Explanation: It the string contains *only* digits, with or without preceding tilda `~`, or *only* "Pos" or "Positive", return 1. Otherwise return the output of the second `ifelse`, which returns 0 if the string contains *only* "Neg" or "Negative", otherwise `NA`.

#### Data:

```r
df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("Neg", "Negative", "32", "16", "64", 
"8", "128", "4", "not done", "Pos", "Missing", "?Pos", "~2", 
"?", "240")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: Is there a way to make one list for all the characters that I want to make "1" and a separate list that is numerical (ie. all numbers greater than 2) that I want to make "1" and choose either option?

Comment: this code is great but doesn't pick up capitilisation eg. POS, POs, NEG

Comment: @sar for case insensitivity add `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex, or use the argument `ignore.case = T` in the `grepl`s.

Comment: regex was my thought too.  +1

Answer (score 2):

You can list down all your conditions in a `case_when` statement. Note that in `case_when` conditions are executed sequentially so if one of the condition is satisfied it doesn't check for other conditions so start with the most specific condition and then add the general ones.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
                         #Has a question mark then NA
  mutate(col = case_when(grepl('\\?', col_1) ~ NA_integer_, 
                         #has "pos" then 1
                         grepl('pos', col_1, ignore.case = TRUE) ~ 1L, 
                         #has "neg" then 1
                         grepl('neg', col_1, ignore.case = TRUE) ~0L, 
                         #Has a number then 1
                         grepl('\\d+', col_1) ~ 1L))

#      col_1 col
#1       Neg   0
#2  Negative   0
#3        32   1
#4        16   1
#5        64   1
#6         8   1
#7       128   1
#8         4   1
#9  not done  NA
#10      Pos   1
#11  Missing  NA
#12     ?Pos  NA
#13       ~2   1
#14    ? 240  NA
```

Note that it is possible to combine multiple conditions into one to shorten the code but I have kept each condition separate for clarity.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col_1 = structure(c(11L, 12L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 9L, 
4L, 7L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("? 240", "?Pos", 
"~2", "128", "16", "32", "4", "64", "8", "Missing", "Neg", "Negative", 
"not done", "Pos"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -14L), 
class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How can I stratify the numeric results? Eg. >=5 is positive and <5 is negative?

Comment: Also, some numbers are preceded by a comment and I want to make these NA. eg. "probably negative 4"

Comment: Because there are so many comments mixed in, can I manually fix some things? eg. "<5" comes up positive but should be negative.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do that. Can you include all the rules that you want to apply in your main post? Maybe also update the example based on these rules @sar

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full `tidyverse` solution that also builds on the other two answers to make them more general. Also, this solution addresses the comment regarding stratifying the numeric values (ie >= 5 is `Positive` and < 5 is `Negative`).

The warning messages are just from calling `as.numeric` on the character vector. Annoying, but I'm not sure how to avoid.

Note: I just chose `Other` as the explicit `NA` level but it can obviously be whatever you want. Also the order of the levels can be put in whatever order needed.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'readr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.5.3
#> Warning: package 'stringr' was built under R version 3.5.2
#> Warning: package 'forcats' was built under R version 3.5.3


df <- structure(list(col_1 = c("Neg", "Negative", "32", "16", "64", 
                               "8", "128", "4", "not done", "Pos", "Missing", "?Pos", "~2", 
                               "?", "240")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -15L))


df %>%
  mutate(
    col = case_when(
      str_detect(col_1, "\\?") ~ NA_character_, # if question mark, return NA
      str_detect(col_1, "^[0-9]*$") ~ col_1, # starts and ends with a number, return value
      str_detect(str_to_lower(col_1), "^pos.*") ~ "Positive", # starts with 'pos' then Positive
      str_detect(str_to_lower(col_1), "^neg.*") ~ "Negative", # starts with 'neg' then Negative
      TRUE ~ NA_character_ # else NA
    ),
    col = factor(
      case_when(
        as.numeric(col) >= 5 ~ "Positive", # >= 5 then Positive per comment
        as.numeric(col) < 5  ~ "Negative", # < 5 then Negative per comment
        TRUE                 ~ col
      ),
      c("Positive", "Negative")
    ) %>% fct_explicit_na("Other") # make a factor and explicitly define NA level
  )
#> Warning in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env): NAs introduced by coercion
#> Warning in eval_tidy(pair$lhs, env = default_env): NAs introduced by coercion
#>       col_1      col
#> 1       Neg Negative
#> 2  Negative Negative
#> 3        32 Positive
#> 4        16 Positive
#> 5        64 Positive
#> 6         8 Positive
#> 7       128 Positive
#> 8         4 Negative
#> 9  not done    Other
#> 10      Pos Positive
#> 11  Missing    Other
#> 12     ?Pos    Other
#> 13       ~2    Other
#> 14        ?    Other
#> 15      240 Positive
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>